# WPF - Put a Story Board into a Resource Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

I have this Story Board in my MainWindow.xaml that basically makes a grid hide and appear.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MenuOpen">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="150"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="MenuClose">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="150"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnOpenMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuOpen}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnCloseMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuClose}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

What I want is to put this whole code into a Resource Dictionary. I already put great part of it in a Dictionary that I've created but this following part I couldn't. I've tried many different ways but none of them seems to work.

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnOpenMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuOpen}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnCloseMenu">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuClose}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Is it possible to put Triggers into a Resource Dictionary or should I use another way? If it is possible what is the correct way to make that work?

Regards.

Comment: The triggers must be applied to some element so it doesn't make much sense to put these in a ResourceDictionary, at least not if they are not part of an element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there another way to put the triggers in a different file? Just to let everything cleaner.

Comment: Yes, you could define them as resources. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define the `EventTriggers` as resources like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MenuOpen">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="50"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="150"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="MenuClose">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridMenu">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="150"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<EventTrigger x:Key="et" RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnOpenMenu">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuOpen}"/>
</EventTrigger>

<EventTrigger x:Key="et2" RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnCloseMenu">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuClose}"/>
</EventTrigger>
```

...and reference them in a window like this:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="et" />
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="et2" />
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: That worked really well. It was exactly what I was expecting! Thank you so much, mm8!